# persist RadComboBox selected item between postbacks

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, telerik

How can I persist selected item between postbacks with RadComboBox? I am loading the database items using WCF service and using LoadonDemand feature.I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you initially loading the data? If you are binding the list box from the database on page load, are you putting that in a     if(!IsPostBack){ ... }  then you won't be loading the data on the post back. Also check that you aren't disabling viewstate on the controls or page. Without more information I can't provide anymore definitive help I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will persist for you automatically if you have ViewState enabled, unless you are accidentally rebinding the data (or resetting the selected item) on postback. http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Be sure to have the ViewState enabled if you use the Checkboxes mode.